# How to crop an image made with pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, standalone

I'm writing this piece of code, which will be an image to incorporate in a paper, and I would like to crop it along the edges of the frame I have drawn. I know the frame is almost the size of the page and so, apparently, there would be no need for any cropping, but this is only a test. I read about the standalone class, which was supposed to solve this problem for me but I don't know what is going on. Could you lend me a helping hand here?

Thank you very much.

```
'\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{pst-plot}
 \usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(6,6)
\psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20](1,2)(0,0)(19.5,26)

\psframe[linewidth=0.065cm,linecolor=black](0,0)(19.5,26)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}'
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` code button to format code blocks rather than the quotation button. Alternatively, ctrl+k. The result should be that each line is indented by 4 spaces and there is no `>` (unless it is part of your code, of course).

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What do you mean that you don't know what is going on? What happens? Do you get an error? If so, what error exactly?

Comment: The problem is that the image is not cropped when I use the standalone class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 \documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
```

Then it uses the dimensions of the pspicture Environment for cropping

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? The starred version of the `pspicture` environment crops what it contains to its dimensions:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

 \usepackage{pstricks-add}
 \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

 \begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(6,6)
\psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20](1,2)(0,0)(19.5,26)

\psframe[linewidth=0.065cm,linecolor=black](0,0)(19.5,26)

\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something along these lines, yes. :)

Comment: What I don't get is why the dimensions of the grid are so different from those of the pspicture environment.

Comment: I copied your code and run it. It does not work for me.

Comment: @Gabu: I suppose you've compiled with `pdflatex`. The `auto-pst-pdf` package is done for that (pdflatex can't manage postscript code by itself). You have to launch pdf latex with the `--enable-write18` switch if you're under MiKTeX, or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Alternative way: compile with `xelatex`.